# SQL remove text at the end and add a prefix

Tags: sql, join, replace, case, prefix

I'm new to SQL and don't know much of the keywords yet.

I have a case to generate a text where the data I pull in example below

Data I pulled is `10DAYS, 20DAYS, 30DAYS`, and so on...

Now, I want to remove the `DAYS` at the end and just add a prefix of `D` at the beginning, resulting in the data:

```
D10, D20, D30...
```

I'm using the `Replace` keyword but I still can't make it to work, hehe

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `REPLACE` to remove the word DAYS from your field:

```
SELECT 'D' + REPLACE(yourfield, 'DAYS', '') 
FROM YourTable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77145/1)

You may need to concatenate your values differently depending on your RDBMS.  Use `CONCAT` for MySql and `||` for Oracle for example.

Answer (score 0):

Without using replace:

```
declare @str nvarchar(50)

set @str = '10days'

declare @index int

set @index = PATINDEX( '%days', @str )

set @str = 'D' + STUFF( @str, @index, 4, '' )

select @str
```